# REST API Server for mobile REST client - How to identify app version?

Tags: android, rest, http

We have developed REST API for our mobile clients (Android). On the server side we have users table when user registers for the first time through our app. Now as we are enhancing our features, it requires modification of existing API's.

The problem is that we don't know which of our users would have the updated version of the app or the old version. How to solve this problem ?

Should have we sent the App version in the HTTP header from devices which would then get stored on our database. Even in this case, a user can login from multiple devices having different app versions.

Is there a recommended approach to solve this problem?

Comment: We have similar problem as you. It seems like treating each device as a user would be more accurate, since one user can have multiple devices with different app versions, but one device can only have 1 app version. Any notification of update would then depend on combination of app version-device ID rather than app version-user ID.

Comment: [API versioning](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#versioning) would have solved your problem!

Comment: One approach would be to add the API version to the header the client is sending to the server. If the header is not there, your server knows that this is version 1, otherwise it reads the header value and handles the request accordingly. Of course if you already rolled out v2 without this header, it may be too late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rule of API versioning: **Don't do it**. Take a different approach:

- Only do backwards compatible changes like adding new fields (and avoid removing or renaming fields).
- If you have to do incompatible changes then add new resources instead and leave the old ones for old clients.
- If you need to do it all over because business has changed too much then add a new API (most often on a second sub-domain).
- Experiment with hypermedia as it will solve *some* of your problems (but not all of course). See for instance http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/12/selling-benefits-of-hypermedia.html for a discussion.

Roy Fielding has an interesting take on it in InfoQ's article here: http://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning.

Mark Nottingham has a similar story to tell here: https://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/07/11/header_versioning.

Comment: yes, add a new resource is correct /v1/resource, /v2/resource. Different resources. Or a second sub domain v1.api.com, v2.api.com. This IS versioning.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you are talking about versioning the mobile app (the REST client) or your URIs (REST API).

To version your API is easy, do the following;

```
/v1/some-resoure
/v2/some-resource
```

Or some people prefer to add versioning to the domain to keep the URIs cleaner;

```
v1.api.com/some-resource
v2.api.com/some-resource
```

For versioning your mobile app, it sounds like your API cares about the version of the app thats being used, is that right? If yes, this is a client state. We need to pass this state in the URI. So you can have;

```
/some-resource?clientVersion=1
/some-resource?clientVersion=2
```

Each call now tells your API which version is being used. I have to say though, this is a bit odd. You shouldn't be coupling your API to your clients like this. Your API should not care what clients are being used, let alone the version. Instead, each client should just be concerned with the version of the API it uses.

If you have version 1 of your client and it relies on a certain thing being true in responses etc from you API, you need to makes sure you version your api (see above). So maybe version 1 of your client only calls `/v1....`

Lets say you now have version 12 of your client, and now you also want to change how your API works. You now have to expose the resources with a different URI version e.g. `/v2...`

Version 12 now only calls `/v2...` URIs. All previous versions of your clients (1 - 11) will not be affected as they are still using `/v1...`

The issue then is how long do you keep versions active on your API? This is a standard versioning question. If you are in control of the API and your clients, you will know how long it can be before you discontinue the clients (1-11) and then can discontinue `/v1...` URIs.

If you don't control the clients, you need to communicate to developers of the client that you will be discontinuing `/v1...`